# Is it possible to enable markup editor in latest Confluence?

Tags: wiki, markup, confluence

Starting from Confluence 4.0, 'wiki' markup language was removed in favor of rich edit. But in my company developers don't like rich edit and want to us familiar markup plain text editor. Is it possible to re-enable wiki markup editing in Confluence? Maybe some addons or modifications exists? It's ok for not 100% conversion between markup and internal omg-woot-xml representations - most of documents has simple layout and for hard cases rich edit can be used.

Comment: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.confluence.wiki

Comment: As described at https://blog.42.nl/articles/confluence-4-x-rich-editor-survival-guide/ use can use the "hidden wiki macro". It is triggered by writing a macro, in the rich text editor, which does not exist, e.g. "{foo}".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to work with wiki markup all you have to do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, while editing a page, and it will open a wiki-markup window.

I don't know of any add-ons which allow anything beyond that, but there could be some in the future.

Comment: The rich text editor also has auto-fill capability for any macros you like to use.

Comment: For which version of Confluence was that available? It does not work for Confluence 5.4.4 ...

Comment: Ctrl shift d still works for me as of Confluence 5.4.2. You can also go to the insert drop down and select wiki markup from there.

Comment: Now I've got it. Do the following: 1. open the visual editor. 2. Press inside the editor CTRL-SHIFT-D, and a popup opens (empty). 3. Insert there your new markup to insert the result in the rendered page in the visual editor then. It would be nice if you could edit existing text as well ...

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more specific in my answer, I'll edit it with the complete process.

Comment: Yes, but it allows to ADD raw-wiki content, not edit existing.

Comment: This appears to no longer work.

Comment: @AndrewProck what version of Confluence are you running? It's still working for me in 5.6.4

Comment: Looks like it's version 1000.132.1

Comment: The shortcut is Cmd+Shift+D on Mac.

Comment: Useless, as long as it doesn't allow editing of existing markup, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I use "Inspect Element" from my browser's developer tools, and just edit the page when the editor is too smart to figure out what I need to do. Very helpful for linked imaged content copied from other pages such as for Jenkins build status icons on engineering pages.